# Graphite metric search using OR operator

Tags: monitoring, graphite

I am trying to fetch a list of metrics via the Render URL API in Graphite, such that only one of the matches are returned. For example, the following, hypothetical scenario:

```
os.redhat.server1.disk1.pct_size_used

os.redhat.server1.disk1.pct_inodes_used
```

So I want to fetch the following for all the disks such that if they are not recording "pct_size_used", the API should return their "pct_inodes_used" metric instead, but in cases where both metrics are recorded, API should only return the "pct_size_used":

```
os.redhat.server1.*.(pct_size_used|pct_inodes_used)
```

Any ideas how to do this? I know Graphite uses the Glob function internally to search for metrics, and Glob function does not support any such operation.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the following syntax:

```
os.redhat.server1.*.{pct_size_used,pct_inodes_used}
```

or, IMHO, a bit cleaner:

```
os.redhat.server1.*.pct_{size,inodes}_used
```

Comment: I think that would be an "AND" operation and op wants an "OR operation